# parsing subprocess stdout values

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

The stdout of given command is in form of iterable string but not printing actual values.

```
import subprocess
subnets = subprocess.run('''aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq -r '.Subnets[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "az1") .SubnetId' ''', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(subnets.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

The stdout is

```
subnet-01234567
subnet-abcdefgh
```

When I am iterating over the stdout, it's iterating in string iterable fashion ex ['s','u','b','n','e'...] but not actual values ex "subnet-01234567, subnet-abcdefgh".
How do I fix it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over the values printed in separate lines I suggest that you separate by new line (`'\n'`):

```
str_out = subnets.stdout.decode('utf-8')
for part in str_out.split('\n'):
    print(part)
```

Comment: great, that worked for me. Appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help. Could you please accept the answer?